# Convert Specific Field of Rows into seperated columns in oracle

Tags: oracle, pivot

i've face with a challenging case. I really appreciate if someone helps ...
imagine we have following set of records:

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 20220614175302951087 | 6/15/2022 13:27 |
| 20220614175302951087 | 6/15/2022 14:06 |
| 20220614175302951088 | 6/15/2022 13:27 |
| 20220614175302951088 | 6/15/2022 14:07 |
| 20220614175302951088 | 6/15/2022 14:42 |
| 20220614175302951089 | 6/15/2022 13:28 |
| 20220614175302951089 | 6/15/2022 14:08 |
| 20220614175302951089 | 6/15/2022 14:39 |
| 20220614175302951090 | 6/15/2022 13:38 |
| 20220614175802951200 | 6/15/2022 9:58 |
| 20220614175802951200 | 6/15/2022 10:28 |

i need the result to be shown as

| ID | Date1 | Date2 | Date3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20220614175302951087 | 6/15/2022 13:27 | 6/15/2022 14:06 |  |
| 20220614175302951088 | 6/15/2022 13:27 | 6/15/2022 14:07 | 6/15/2022 14:42 |
| 20220614175302951089 | 6/15/2022 13:28 | 6/15/2022 14:08 | 6/15/2022 14:39 |
| 20220614175802951200 | 6/15/2022 9:58 | 6/15/2022 10:28 |  |

thank you guys

Comment: If you've tagged `pivot` then it seems that you know the function you need. Can you please describe an issue you currently have with the code?

Comment: Are the maximum no of rows 3. Or they could be any no and then you need the columns as Date4, Date5, Date6 etc...

Comment: @AnkitBajpai
Hi, Yes. it's maximum 3.

Comment: @astentx
Hi,
as i tried, none of pivot modes i know, couldn't cover this case. i tagged whether somebody knows other modes.

Comment: But you didn't provide either current code or description of what is missing in your approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the no of dates are maximum 3, You can use the conditional aggregation method along with ROW_NUMBER, to achieve your result -

```
SELECT ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN DATE ELSE NULL END) Date1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN DATE ELSE NULL END) Date2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN DATE ELSE NULL END) Date3
  FROM (SELECT ID, DATE,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE)
          FROM YOUR_TABLE)
 GROUP BY ID;
```